# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have defined a JS array as below:

```
var forecastJSArray=new Array();
```

and then I am trying to add my json objects into this array using push, as below:

```
$.getJSON("api-detail.json")
  .then(function (forecast){
    $.each(forecast, function() {
      self.forecastJSArray.push({
         rank: this.rank,
         rep: this.rep,
         total: this.total,
      });
    });
  })
;
```

But when I run this code, it gives me an error as:
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

My final array should look like this:

```
[
  {
     "rank" : 1, 
     "rep" : "rep1", 
     "total" : 10,
  }, {
    //...etc
  }
]
```

Would be really grateful if someone can give me an idea where I am going wrong with this. Thanks a lot in advance.

**EDIT:**
The code is enclosed inside an oracle-jet view model (which uses knockoutjs view model), and this is something like this, with a RequireJS block:

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojselectcombobox', 
'ojs/ojtable', 'ojs/ojbutton'], function(oj, ko, $) {

    function DashboardViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        ... earlier code
        ... earlier code
    }
    return new DashboardViewModel();
});
```

as $.getJSON returns asynchronously, I am finding it difficult to use the data outside the callback function. So trying to push the data into a JS array first. Please let me know if you need any additional information. TIA.

Comment: remove `self.`.

Answer (score 1):

First, from your side it is not possible to understand whether you have defined `self` anywhere.

Secondly, you have created an array `forecastJSArray`

You can try by removing the self & directly refer the array

```
forecastJSArray.push({
  rank: this.rank,
  rep: this.rep,
  total: this.total,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`var forecastJSArray` defines `forecastJSArray` in the scope of a function or in the global scope.

`self.forecastJSArray` would only work if  `self` refers to `window` and `forecastJSArray`is defined in the global scope. In general you should not define a variable in the global scope.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tells you that `self` is `undefined` (not holding any value).

So if `var forecastJSArray` defined in a reachable scope for the code in the `$.each(forecast, function() {` callback, then you would write: `forecastJSArray.push` without the `self.`.